# Jquery как добавить класс к одному из элементов с одинаковым классом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мне необходимо добавлять класс к одному из элементов, которые содержат один и тот же класс.

```js
    $('.dashboard__works-todo-active, .dashboard__works-more-button').click(function() {
        if ($('.dashboard__works-more').hasClass('dashboard__works-more-active')){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.dashboard__works-more').removeClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
            }, 200);
            $('.dashboard__works-more').css("opacity","0");
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.dashboard__works-more').css("opacity","1");
            }, 200);
            $('.dashboard__works-more').addClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
        }
    });
```

```css
.dashboard__works-more{
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

.dashboard__works-more-active{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <div class="dashboard__works-todo">
                <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-todo-active">Get 3 Quotes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard__works-more">
                <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
                    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
                    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">
                    Close
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
                       <div class="dashboard__works-todo">
                <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-todo-active">Get 3 Quotes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard__works-more">
                <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
                    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
                    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">
                      Close
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Подскажите как можно оптимизировать этот код чтобы он работал? Всем заранее спасибо за любую помощь!!!

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что этот код добавляет класс dashboard__works-more-active ко всем элементам класса dashboard__works-more, а мне нужно чтобы только к одному

Comment: Повесь на див id о присвой ему класс.

Comment: У меня таких элементов много будет (например от 2 до 100), мне нужно чтобы это работало без добавления лишних id и классов, так как вешать 100+ id не имеет смысла

Comment: Я могу показать как это сделать на ванильном js, если вас устроит.

Comment: Да, вполне, покажите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('dashboard__works-todo-active'))
    e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('dashboard__works-more-active')

  if (e.target.classList.contains('dashboard__works-more-button'))
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle('dashboard__works-more-active')
})
```

```css
.dashboard__works-more {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.dashboard__works-more-active {
  display: flex;
  animation: 1s fade-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-todo-active">Get 3 Quotes</a>
</div>

<div class="dashboard__works-more">
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-todo-active">Get 3 Quotes</a>
</div>

<div class="dashboard__works-more">
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нравится +1.

Comment: Это решение не работает на Safari и мобильных устройствах

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.dashboard__works-more').fadeOut(0);

$('.dashboard__works-todo a').click(function() {
  const dataLinkId = $(this).data('link-id');
  if ($(this).hasClass('dashboard__works-more-active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
    $(`[data-show="${dataLinkId}"]`).fadeOut(300);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
    $(`[data-show="${dataLinkId}"]`).fadeIn(300);
  }
});

$('.dashboard__works-more-button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('dashboard__works-more-active').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
.dashboard__works-more-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;" data-link-id="1">Get 3 Quotes</a>
</div>
<div class="dashboard__works-more" data-show="1">
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">
                    Close
                    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;" data-link-id="2">Get 3 Quotes</a>
</div>
<div class="dashboard__works-more" data-show="2">
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">
                      Close
                    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2 (изменил вёрстку):

```js
$('.dashboard__works-more').fadeOut(0);

$('.dashboard__works-todo a').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('dashboard__works-more-active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
    $(this).parent().find('.dashboard__works-more').fadeOut(300);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('dashboard__works-more-active');
    $(this).parent().find('.dashboard__works-more').fadeIn(300);
  }
});

$('.dashboard__works-more-button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('dashboard__works-more-active').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
.dashboard__works-more-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;">Get 3 Quotes</a>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
      <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
      <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard__works-todo">
  <a href="javascript: void 0;">Get 3 Quotes</a>
  <div class="dashboard__works-more">
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-left">
      <div class="dashboard__works-more-text">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__works-more-right">
      <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="dashboard__works-more-button">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но повторюсь, у меня будет много подобных элементов и  data-link-id="1" не совсем то, что мне подходит