# Как закрыть меню?

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование

Имеем вот такой код html с менюшкой и двумя кнопками(первая - иконка менюшки, вторая - иконка крестика)

```
<i class="fas fa-align-right" id="navToggle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-times" id="navClose"></i>
<div class="nav-open">
    ....
</div>
```

К каждому прописаны свои стили, а также стили при его активации или открытия

```
.nav-open {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #0A36B5;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .55s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
              transform-origin: top right;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
              transform: scale(0);
      visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-open.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
}
.fas.fa-align-right.active {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fas.fa-times {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 7;
  display: none;
}
.fas.fa-times.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #111;
  z-index: 7;
  display: initial;
}
```

А вот этим кодом на JQuery я добавляю активные классы

```
$("#navToggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#navClose").toggleClass("active")
    $(".nav-open").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064120/jquery-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc/1064140#1064140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы закрыть меню нужно:

1) Сделать крестик видимым для пользователя. Для этого к вашему классу .fas.fa-times.active нужно добавить

```
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
```

2) Добавить обработчик для крестика:

```
$("#navClose").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#navToggle").toggleClass("active")
  $(".nav-open").toggleClass("open");
});
```

---

Но для оптимизации кода, я бы сделала по-другому немного:
1) Заменила селекторы с таких .fas.fa-times на .close-btn, например
2) Добавила для самой кнопки #navToggle, когда она имеет класс active (чтобы она была видна пользователю)

```
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
```

3) Меняла бы при клике на кнопку #navToggle класс fa-align-right на fa-times (при следующем клике - обратно). Чтобы использовать лишь 1 кнопку.
4) Использовала бы лишь 1 обработчик для 1 кнопки:

```
$("#navToggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".nav-open").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: 3) Меняла бы при клике на кнопку #navToggle класс fa-align-right на fa-times (при следующем клике - обратно). Чтобы использовать лишь 1 кнопку. 4) Использовала бы лишь 1 обработчик для 1 кнопки: - Ваши слова
Как мне так сделать?
И кнопка видна для пользователя, просто она не работала

Comment: @Рома, вы можете посмотреть оба варианта тут: [пример с вашими 2 кнопками и вариант с использованием 1 кнопки](https://jsfiddle.net/melai17/0zgbjr54/18/)